# Bitcoin Vanitygen > how to edit .cl kernel file to so that it will verify the public key directly instead

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

So im trying to create a vanityaddress, which is 1 followed by my 10 chars plus some random chars, no matter how i try i get 9 right out of my chars  not the 10th chars , so i everyday get bunch of address but not the one  i want, i dont care what it comes after 1oth char,  is there a way to narrow down your search, ? or how to edit the .cl kernal file  see verify the public key directly instead of converting it to an address and then comparing it.  costum seed file etc , how ....

1Mycharsss?XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Each additional specific character you want in your vanity address will make the search 58x as long. In other words, you will find 58x as many 9 character matches, as 10 character matches. If the vanity generator is working otherwise, just keep searching.

> how to edit the .cl kernal file see verify the public key directly instead of converting it to an address and then comparing it

No, there is no way to tell what the address will be, without converting the public key to an address. Part of the address derivation involves hash functions, so you cannot know the output just by looking at the input value, you must invoke the hash function to get this. The best you can do is to randomly pick private keys, and then derive the address of each one and check to see if it matches your desired string.

Comment: thank you, another question, i thought i might achieve tht with seedin it manually , at the best they will be used as salt but is there any specefic format for seed files ? bin files hex files.

Comment: No, there is no way that you can select a seed that will illicit a better-than-random-chance to get the desired vanity address.

Comment: :| , yeah but what is the right format should be binary , hex ,,,,, i cont do any thing els as far as i know, at this point i dont care about the address anymnore, i just have to do this:) thank you